# How do I stop removing double quotes after passing command-line argument?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

Hi I'm trying to pass json in terminal as a payload input but after passing argument in terminal I got json without double quotes, I want to have my response output in json format as well.

How do I stop removing double quotes after passing command-line argument?

Here is my code,

```
def get_apicall():
        Token = get_token()
        url = "http://localhost.../resp"
        Header = {'Content-Type': "application/json", 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + str(Token)}
        payload = sys.argv[1]
        print(payload)
        payload1 = json.dumps(payload )
        print(payload1)
        response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload1, headers=Header)
        print(response.text)
    get_endpoint()
```

My input json is `{ "request":"success","input":[ { "type":" ", "content":[ { "type":" ", "meta":{ "sample_type":" " , deatail":" "} ] } ], "output":[ { "type":" ","content":[ { "type":"", "meta":{  "sample_type":"",  },  "deatils":" " } ] }  ] }`

When I'm trying to print input payload which I passed in teminal `payload = sys.argv[1]  print(payload)`

but I got this when I did print(payload) which removed double qoutes : `{ request:success,input:[ { type: , content:[ { type: , meta:{ sample_type:  , deatail: } ] } ], output:[ { type: ,content:[ { type:, meta:{  sample_type:,  },  deatils:  } ] }  ] }`

please correct me if I'm wrong some where in my above code.

I want to have `print(payload)` same as my input payload

```
{ "request":"success","input":[ { "type":" ", "content":[ { "type":" ", "meta":{ "sample_type":" " , deatail":" "} ] } ], "output":[ { "type":" ","content":[ { "type":"", "meta":{  "sample_type":"",  },  "deatils":" " } ] }  ] }`
```

Comment: How so you call the script?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Quotes, no quotes, what’s important is what the values _are_, their type. Please forget the quotation marks and be clear about the values and their types.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `print()` function can apply different formatting for printing. Maybe try using `repr()` function which will show the object based on the way Python is interpreting it. I.e. it will include type information like quotes for strings, square brackets for lists, and curly braces for dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print JSON using `print()`, which formats JSON (removes double quotes).

If you want to keep the quotes in the output, use `json.dumps()` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.htm)) in `print()` instead. That is, just replace `print(payload)` with `print(json.dumps(payload))` in your code.

So, the following code will work for you:

```py
import json

print(json.dumps(payload))
```